# IN onc RPC , which are the server files and which are the client files? what is significance of files?

Tags: c, client-server, rpc

I have complied and run the code on a single machine , If I want to run the code on multiple machines in a client server architecture , which file do I place on server and which file do I place on client ?[image: the files finally generated after using make command]

Comment: This really depends on your implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming green indicates an executable file and that the file names follow normal naming practices.

Put `int_client` on the clients.

Put `int_server` on the server(s).